# integer $a$ for which $x^3-3x+a = 0$ has $3$ distinct real roots in $x\in (0,1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If the equation $x^3-3x+a=0$ has $3$ distinct roots between $0$ and $1$ then the integer value of $a$ is

Can we solve it without Calculus.

$\bf{My\; Try}::$ Let $x=2\cos \phi$, where $-1\leq \cos \phi\leq 1\Rightarrow 0\leq \phi \leq \pi$(Principle value, Inverse exists)

$\displaystyle 8\cos^3 \phi-6\cos \phi+a = 0\Rightarrow 4\cos^3 \phi-3\cos \phi = -\frac{a}{2}\Rightarrow \cos 3\phi = -\frac{a}{2}$

Now $-1\leq \cos 3\phi\leq 1$, So $\displaystyle -1 \leq -\frac{a}{2}\leq 1\Rightarrow -2\leq a\leq 2$

So we get $a = \left\{-2,-1,0,1,2\right\}$

But answer is no integer value of $a$

Help me

Thanks

Comment: Did you plot $x~ vs. ~a$? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E3-3x+%3D+a

Comment: Draw the graph of $y=x^3-3x$, and raise it an integral number of units. Seems to me that you’re *never* going to get three roots in $\langle0,1\rangle$.

Comment: @Amzoti: That's an answer, in my opinion.

Comment: @EricStucky: Thanks, looks like Kelvin gave a nice answer. Regards

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Indeed there is no value of $a$ which satisfy the criteria. We can use the sum of roots formula based on the coefficient of $x^2$ which is 0. It is impossible for 3 distinct real roots in $(0,1)$ to sum up to 0.

Comment: Nice. This shows that we don't even need "integer" or "distinct" in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Also, the product of the roots is $-a$. Since the roots are all between 0 and 1, $a$ can't be an integer.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

If two roots are same we can write $$x^3-3x+a=(x-c)(x-b)^2$$

Compare the coefficients of the different powers of $x$  to determine $a,b,c,d$

If three roots are same we can write $$x^3-3x+a=(x-d)^3$$

Comparing the coefficients of $x^2, d=0\implies a=0$

Answer (score 1):

If we factor the polynomial as $(x - b)(x - c)(x - d)$, we have

$$a = -bcd$$

But since $0 < b, c, d < 1$, we have that $|a| < 1$; the only integer satisfying this is zero, which certainly doesn't work.

Comment: You can say: since $0 < b, c, d < 1$, we have $0 < |a| = |bcd| < 1$, and there is no integer satisfying this.